# Regex Conditional replacement on Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have some numbers on which I want to apply some regex replacement.

+000123,456

+123

000123,456

123

+123.45

-123,45

I want to remove the + sign if present and replace the comma with a dot.
The difficult part is that not all the numbers are decimals.

I don't use regex really often, so I usually use [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oVhLeS/1) to do some tests.

In this case, I created the following regular expression:

```
([+]*)([0-9]+)(([,])([0-9]+))*
```

1st capturing group: `([+]*)`

2nd capturing group: `([0-9]+)`

3rd capturing group: `(([,])([0-9]+))*`

4th capturing group: `([,])`

5th capturing group: `([0-9]+)`

and substitution :

```
$2${3:+.$5:}
```

Explanation: use 2nd capturing group, then if 3rd capturing group is present use DOT and 5th capturing group, else nothing

and seems to work fine, but trying to replicate the same on Java, it's not working:

```
private String replaceUsingRegex(final String line) {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([+]*)([0-9]+)(([,])([0-9]+))*");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(line);
    return regexMatcher.replaceAll("$2${3:+.$5:}");
}
```

gived me an IllegalArgumentException at the third line:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: named capturing group is missing trailing '}'
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendExpandedReplacement(Matcher.java:1051)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:997)
    at java.base/java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:1181)
    at com.mytest.TestRegex.replaceUsingRegex(TestRegex.java:20)
```

I also tried to use the [java generated code by rege101](https://regex101.com/r/oVhLeS/1/codegen?language=java) but is still not working.

Comment: Does your input data only consist of these numbers, or does the regex pattern need to find them within a larger body of text? If the former, I'd suggest doing a simple character replacement on `+` and then another replacement on `,`. No need to bundle it all into one big regex pattern.

Comment: Does it have to be a single operation?

Comment: @CAustin Even if they're in a block of text, you can search for the general pattern and modify each on replace using the functional [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.util.function.Function)).

Comment: @shmosel not necessarily

Comment: So do `line.replaceFirst("^\\+", "").replace(',', '.')`

Comment: @CAustin yes, is part of a larger body text, a csv basically, but I'm splitting each line by separator, and I will apply only on those fields that contain only numbers and symbols (+ - , . )

Comment: Do you want to retain the leading zeros?

Comment: @WJS not necessarily

Comment: be advised to select Java if testing regular expressions for Java. You selected PCR3 (PHP): [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEIGZ.png) - when you select Java and hover of the substitution text, you'll see that `${3:+...` is not a conditional replacement since not available in Java, actually shown as [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqj7O.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"... IllegalArgumentException at the third line ..."*

The reason you're receiving this error is because the Java regex implementation does not recognize the "conditional" replacement syntax of `$2${3:+.$5:}`.
The `${ }` construct is expected to contain only a literal reference to a capturing group.

For example, `(?<name>abc)`, and `${name}`.

I believe the syntax you're using is specific to the *perl*, *PCRE*, implementation.
*[Perldoc – perlre – Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)*.
*[Perldoc – perlretut – Perl regular expressions tutorial](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut#Search-and-replace)*.

Here are the JavaDocs for both the *Pattern* and *Matcher* classes.
You can find the complete syntax specifications on the *Pattern* JavaDoc page.
*[Pattern (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)*.
*[Matcher (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)*.

And, a relevant excerpt,
*[Matcher#appendReplacement (Java SE 20 & JDK 20)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,java.lang.String))*.

> *"... The replacement string may contain references to subsequences captured during the previous match: Each occurrence of ${name} or $g will be replaced by the result of evaluating the corresponding group(name) or group(g) respectively. For $g, the first number after the $ is always treated as part of the group reference. Subsequent numbers are incorporated into g if they would form a legal group reference. Only the numerals '0' through '9' are considered as potential components of the group reference. ..."*

There are a few things you can do to parse the values.

> *"... I want to remove the + sign if present and replace the comma with a dot. The difficult part is that not all the numbers are decimals. ..."*

If the values will only ever have 1 comma, and a possible + character, you can just use a *[String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence))* call.

```java
String[] strings = {
    "+000123,456",
    "+123",
    "000123,456",
    "123",
    "+123.45",
    "-123,45"
};
for (String string : strings) {
    string = string.replace("+", "").replace(",", ".");
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Output

```
000123.456
123
000123.456
123
123.45
-123.45
```

This, of course, would not suffice when the numbers are within a text which also contains unrelated commas and plus signs.

For this you can use the *Pattern* and *Matcher* class, to capture the values, and then append them to a new *[StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)* instance.

The pattern will be,

```
\+?(-?\d+)(?:[,.](\d+))?
```

```java
String string = "abc, +000123,456 def +123, ghi 000123,456 jkl, 123 mno +123.45, pqr -123,45";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\+?(-?\\d+)(?:[,.](\\d+))?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
StringBuilder stringB = new StringBuilder();
int offset = 0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    stringB.append(string, offset, matcher.start());
    stringB.append(matcher.group(1));
    if (matcher.group(2) != null) stringB.append(".").append(matcher.group(2));
    offset = matcher.end();
}
```

Output

```
abc, 000123.456 def 123, ghi 000123.456 jkl, 123 mno 123.45, pqr -123.45
```

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, a regex is overkill for this. First, just replace the plus sign, then replace the comma.

```
String[] values = {
        "+000123,456","+123","000123,456","123","+123.45","-123,45"
};

for (String value : values) {
    String s = value.replace("+", "").replace(",", ".");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

prints

```
000123.456
123
000123.456
123
123.45
-123.45
```

You could also write a lambda to do it.

```
UnaryOperator<String> convert = str->str.replace("+", "").replace(",", ".");
String result = convert.apply("+1202,233");
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
1202.233
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String replaceUsingRegex(final String line) {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(\\+?)(0*)([0-9]+)([,\\.])?([0-9]+)?");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(line);

    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        String result = regexMatcher.group(3).replaceFirst("^0+", "");
        if (regexMatcher.group(4) != null && regexMatcher.group(5) != null) {
            result += "." + regexMatcher.group(5);
        }
        return result;
    }

    return line;
}
```

1st capturing group: `(\\+?)` - leading '+' sign 
2nd capturing group: `(0*)` - zeroes more than 1 
3rd capturing group: `([0-9]+)` - All digits before dot/comma 
4th capturing group: `([,\\.]?)` - Comma and dot, optional 
5th capturing group: `([0-9]+)?` - Digits after separator